# Filter kubectl get based on annotation

Tags: kubernetes, get, annotations

I would like to filter my `kubectl get deploy` command based on the value of an annotation.

Something similar to `kubectl get deploy --annotation stork.libopenstorage.org/skipresource!="true"`

Currently no clue how to do this and we don't want to add an extra label. Output of both commands above should be something like below:

```
kubectl get deploy 
NAME                        READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
elastalert                  1/1     1            1           33d
es-hq                       1/1     1            1           33d
etcdsnapshots               1/1     1            1           33d
fluentd-aggregator          2/2     2            2           33d
kibana                      1/1     1            1           33d

kubectl get deploy --annotation stork.libopenstorage.org/skipresource!="true"
NAME                        READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
etcdsnapshots               1/1     1            1           33d
fluentd-aggregator          2/2     2            2           33d
kibana                      1/1     1            1           33d

kubectl get deploy --annotation stork.libopenstorage.org/skipresource="true"
NAME                        READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
elastalert                  1/1     1            1           33d
es-hq                       1/1     1            1           33d
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I have a deployment with the annotation prometheus.io/scrape="true"

I can get the deployments having that annotation by

```
kubectl get deploy -o=jsonpath='{.items[?(@.spec.template.metadata.annotations.prometheus\.io/scrape=="true")].metadata.name}'
```

The above uses the Jsonpath concept and the docs can be found at [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/)

In your case the command might be like

```
kubectl get deploy -o=jsonpath='{.items[?(@.spec.template.metadata.annotations.stork\.libopenstorage\.org/skipresource=="true")].metadata.name}'
```

This concept can be applied to other kubernetes resources as well.One other command that might help in understanding the earlier commands is

```
 kubectl get deployment -o=json
```

Comment: Thanks! This was particularly helpful while trying to get the name of the default storageclass (which, for reasons beyond my comprehension, is an annotation rather than a label):

`kubectl get storageclass -o=jsonpath='{.items[?(@.metadata.annotations.storageclass\.kubernetes\.io/is-default-class= ="true")].metadata.name}'`

Comment: **Hint:** for intelligent people like me, which are searching for the same but in context of service accounts and the related secret.  The `ServiceAccount` resource has the ref itself!

Answer (score 7):

There is not way to do the filtering by annotation at the server side, but you can get the list of all pods or deployements and filter it locally, with clever use of `-o=jsonpath` or using `jq` which I find more intuitive.

For example to get all deployments where that particular annotation is not `"true"`

```
 kubectl get deployment -o json| jq '.items[].metadata|select(.annotations."stork.libopenstorage.org/skipresource"!="true")|.name'
```

or for pods that have the annotation `aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch-agent-ignore`:

```
 kubectl get pods -n mynamespace -o json| jq '.items[].metadata|select(.annotations."aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch-agent-ignore"!="true")|.name'
```

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to use annotations in the same way that labels are used. The thing is that annotations are not meant to be used like that. It's possible to achieve what you want as [sachin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62267578/12153576) described but this is not practical.

[Here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/18801#issuecomment-530025542) we can read:

> You cannot query annotations in Kubernetes, and this will not change
>   in the foreseeable future.

Using labels would be a much better solution. [Here](https://multinode-kubernetes-cluster.readthedocs.io/en/latest/06-k8s-labels_anotations_selectors.html) we can see many usage examples for labels and it makes very clear why using it makes sense.

I think this is not the exact answer you was looking for, but in my opinion you are trying to do something in the hard way and it doesn't need to be like that if you use the solution that was created for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The problem with labels is that they have a 63 character limit.

Comment: There are all interesting, and there are valid use cases to query for them.
Even if K8S developers have their narrow view of what is intended use, people will use `jq` to filter.