# How to exclude fields in kubectl get

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

When running `kubectl get -o yaml`, I would like to filter out the annotation `kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration` so results are easier to read. Is there a native way of doing this with kubectl?

Comment: Does this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62264658/filter-kubectl-get-based-on-annotation) help you with your problem?

Answer (score 0):

There's no native way of doing that, but you can postprocess the results using something like [`yq`](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/):

```
kubectl get pod example -o yaml |
  yq -y 'del(.metadata.annotations."kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration")'
```

There is a plugin called [`neat`](https://github.com/itaysk/kubectl-neat) that does this sort of clean up for you, it acts as a filter just like `yq` in the previous example:

```
kubectl get pod example -o yaml | kubectl neat
```